# Firebase Hosting Angular Throws error only in production

Tags: angular, firebase, hosting, production, firebase-hosting

I have an Angular App hosted at Firebase Hosting. It run perfectly in my machine (development environment), but it never ran properly at Production Environment.
It uses AngularFireDatabase to access data at Firebase Realtime Database.
All logic works perfectly at development, but when I run "ng build --prod" and deploy it using "firebase deploy", the published app just doesn't work.
My "dist" folder seems to be just fine, too.

At my browser's console log I read this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Av(...).database is not a function
TypeError: Av(...).database is not a function
    at main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1
    at e.invoke (polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1)
    at t.run (polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1)
    at t.runOutsideAngular (main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1)
    at new t (main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1)
    at main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1
    at Bo (main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1)
    at Uo (main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1)
    at t.get (main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1)
    at main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1
    at P (polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1)
    at polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.8544df07846da1211bdc.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1)
    at g (polyfills.0fa3e9588b07b25d43c2.js:1)
```

I'm using:

```
@angular/core: ^7.2.15,
@angular/fire: ^5.2.1
```

Please ... if someone already had this issue (and solved), HELP ME!

Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is enough here to help debug. These versions work fine for me.

Comment: I have a very similar problem [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253896/angular-8-cannot-read-property-runoutsideangular-of-undefined?), maybe it's a firebase thing..